# Do I need to have separate structs for each use case in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am building a simple REST API for my blog using Golang. I store my posts in MongoDB, so, when I retrieve some record, I have to serialize (not sure if it's a right term) to native Golang type (struct). Since I have multiple endpoints with different return types, it seems like I have to have a bunch of similar types with difference in only one field. This needed when I perform $lookup operation, which is basically the analog of join operation in relational DBs.

I think the problem I meant will be clear from example:

```
type Post struct {
  title string
  author string
  category string
}

type Author struct {
  firstname string
  lastname string
}

type Category struct {
  name string
  parent Category
}

type PostWithAuthor struct {
  title string
  author Author
  category string
}

type PostWithCategory struct {
  title string
  author string
  category Author
}

type PostWithAuthorAndCategory struct {
  title string
  author Author
  category Category
}


func getPost() (Post) {
  
}

func getPostWithCategory() (PostWithCategory) {

}

func getPostWithAuthor() (PostWithAuthor) {

}

func getPostWithAuthorAndCategory() (PostWithAuthorAndCategory) {

}
```

Comment: You may use a struct with all fields, and only the ones you query (select) will be filled. You may use a map which may hold arbitrary elements. Or you may use multiple structs as in your example. It's up to you, all solutions have their pros and cons.

Comment: If you plan to use Marshal/Unmarshal functions to serialize your data, the fields of the structures should be capitalized: `Title`, `Author`, `Category`, etc.

Comment: @PakUula yeah yeah, this was just quick example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a struct inside another struct.

```
type Post struct {
  Title string
  Author Author
  Category Category
}

type Author struct {
  FirstName string
  LastName string
}

type Category struct {
  Name string
  Parent *Category
}

// Query via `gorm`
var posts []Post
db.Where(&Post{Category: Category{Name: "food"}}).Find(&posts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please check my question carefully. I know that and I showed that I use this in other structs. The reason why I need basic struct where all fields are strings is that I need to return 'raw" posts from some methods, but in others I need to join category or author or both and my question was do I really need to create separate struct for each case?